# Google Analytics API login error

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, statistics

2 days ago I wrote a site for my school, and today I decided to analyze it with Google Analytics. The Google Analytics is working well, but I wanted to embed the stats into the site's admin panel. And the problem is that if I log into Google, I get an error on the console:

`GET https://content.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accountSummaries 403 (OK)`

You can login to the admin here: [krudynyh.hu/admin](http://krudynyh.hu/admin), username: test, password: samplepassword.